# How to show labels on matplotlib plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

When I execute the following code, it doesn't produce a plot with a label.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(1, 5)
plt.plot(x, x*1.5, label='Normal')
```

Numpy version is '1.6.2'
Matplotlib version is '1.3.x'

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 135, accepted):

You forgot to display the [legend](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.legend):

```
...
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to show the labels next to the lines, there's a matplotlib extension package [`matplotx`](https://pypi.org/project/matplotx/) (can be installed via `pip install matplotx[all]`) that has a method that does that.

```py
import matplotx

x = np.arange(1, 5)
plt.plot(x, x*1.5, label='Normal')
plt.plot(x, x*2, label='Quadratic')
matplotx.line_labels()
```

[image: img]

N.B. A similar task using only matplotlib would look like:

```py
x = np.arange(1, 5)
y = x*1.5
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.text(x[-1]*1.05, y[-1], 'Normal', color=plt.gca().get_lines()[0].get_color());
```

Answer (score 0):

to add label

> plt.xlabel('*insert your label*')

> plt.ylabel('*insert your label*')

> plt.title('*insert title*')